httpclient calls getting queued up in the server causing performance issues in the application
We have an application built around .NET 4.8. There are 4 servers for the application in production and has a heavy usage of http calls to get data. The  outbound http calls are done from the application via httpclient class. However, it seems like the httpclient calls are getting queued and we could see the defaultconnectionlimit property has been set to 20. Some of the outbound http calls are also pretty slow with some taking more than 10-20s at times.The application is extremely slow during peak load hours and the server parameters like CPU, memory are all below 20%.
Does increasing the value for below mentioned property has an effect on this? If yes, what would be the ideal value so that we can configure it accordingly and utilize the resources in the servers in an optimal way.
FYI: The application makes atleast 100k outbound http calls from application in 1hour during peak load hours.
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20; // We are trying to identify whether this is the root cause of the problem

At a guess, I'd say you're misusing HttpClient. Check out You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software and the follow-up You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software. You're aiming for about 28 calls per second, which I'd think is perfectly doable.

You might also want to investigate why the server is slow. If CPU and memory usage is low it just means the bottleneck is somewhere else. If there is a database it should have a dashboard, it might tell you if calls are blocking on locks for example.

@ProgrammingLlama The best practices mentioned in the links are already followed. At peak loads may be outbound http requests at a time would be more than 100 per second on a single server

@JonasH All the database calls are optimized, the queueing happens in IIS for APIs consuming httpclient whereas those using direct DB calls are working fine

I have to admit that I don't know the area very well, but I think it is very likely that this is causing you issues (assuming you are using HTTPClient correctly), as you have a decent number of outbound requests in your peak hour.
Try increasing it gradually, say 50 then 100 as your next steps, and monitor your metrics to see the impact of the changes.
Don't forget that you will also need to monitor your network infrastructure to ensure that it can cope with an increase.  You also don't want to overload it.
The issue is trying to find the right balance and latency, and where the limit lies with your application and infrastructure.
This will be very environment specific.  So you just have to test and try what works best for you in this case.
